# Entering Romania with single entry Bulgaria visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, romania, bulgaria

I hold an Indian passport and have a single entry Bulgaria visa. I hope to enter Bulgaria on a day trip by road from Macedonia, and then later fly from Albania to Romania (within the Bulgaria visa validity period). Can I do this given the visa mentions single entry?

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to :

TIMATIC (the database that airlines use for documentation) state :

> ### Romania - Destination Visa
>
> #### Visa Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a “C" visa issued by Bulgaria or Cyprus, valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.

A single entry visa becomes invalid as soon as you have used up that entry and leave the country. You can either invert your itinerary and go to Romania first, then Bulgaria, or get a Romanian visa